# Find text input with certain value to append

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox that when I check it will append a URL link already existing inside the `value` attribute. I was hoping someone could shed light on the easiest way to both select the text inside the input field and check if it contains `iframe` code. An example of what I am working with:

```
<input type="text" value="<iframe src="www.site.com/embed/3243/"></iframe>" class="text"  />
```

Basically, I need to select the input value and check that it contains the word "iframe" in the `value` attribute and then append it. I need to check because there are other text inputs on the page so I need to be sure it's the correct one.

An example of what I want to be able to achieve once I click on the checkbox is to have the textbox value change to:

```
www.site.com/embed/3243/?autoplay=true
```

I have tried a few different methods, but I know they are incorrect so I won't post them here to avoid confusion. I don't need help with the checkbox, just selecting the value attribute and checking if it contains the word "iframe". I should be okay with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change()
{
var val = document.getElementById('a').value;
if (val.indexOf('iframe') > -1)
{
  val = val.split('"');
  val[1] += '?autoplay=true';
  val = val.join('"');
  document.getElementById('a').value = val;
}
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text" value='<iframe src="www.site.com/embed/3243/"></iframe>' class="text"  />
<button onclick='change()'>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: I don't have an id attribute to use, I am using an existing template system which can't really be altered without causing problems elsewhere.

Comment: Can you not even add one `id`? If not, just have it check everything starting with `input`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.write($("input").val().split("'")[1] + "?autoplay=true");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="<iframe src='www.site.com/embed/3243/'></iframe>" class="text" />
```

You should change the quotation marks of the value to this ' simple quotations and then you can get the value.